# How to refrence another variable from different clases in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So im trying to refrence a variable called high score in a diffrent file in a class called PlayScene. How do i refrence that high score in my GameScene.swift file. Here is my GameScene.swift file currently but at the line with

```
self.highscoreText.text = "Highscore: \(highscoreshow)
```

it says that highscoreshow is an unresolved identifier because I don't know how to refrence that variable from another class

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"play")
    let title = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "title")
    let highscoreText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.title.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 150
            , CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 150)
        self.highscoreText.text = "Highscore: \(highscore)"
        self.highscoreText.fontSize = 42
        self.highscoreText.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 150)
        self.addChild(self.playButton)
        self.addChild(self.title)
        self.addChild(self.highscoreText)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Here is the function in the other class in which the highscore variable is created and stored:

```
func died() {

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults()

    var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    if (score > highscore){

        defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")

    }

    var highscoreshow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed `highscore` is an _unresolved_ identifier. It can't magically find out which `highscore` you want to use

Comment: No what I mean is that i have it resolved in another class. so how do I acces it @BryanChen

Comment: Please remove the irrelevant methods, and add more information about the other class, so we can more easily understand the question.

Comment: Ok i did. Can you please help me now @jtbandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are 2 problems.

1. It is possible that the variable **highscoreshow** does not exist when you try to access it.
2. The variable highscoreshow can be accessed only within the method PlayScene.died (where it is declared).

You could use NSUserDefaults to share the value `highscoreshow` between 2 Scenes.

1. Just add this line in GameScene of top of the method **didMoveToView**

   `var highscoreshow = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")`
2. Remember to update the value in NSUserDefaults if you change highscore

   `NSUserDefaults().setInteger(highscoreshow, forKey: "highscore")`
3. Finally please note that values NSUserDefaults are save on persistent storage. So these values will still be available if you restart the app or the device.

Hope this will help.